# How to use distinct and group by in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct

I have a query that joins several tables , and I need to get the count of items of the table bills, but the table details_bills make the result of Count function bigger. But if I write distinct in that field I got an error.

Query

```
SELECT bill.Periodo, Count(bill.Id) AS bill_counts
FROM (select id,comprobante,suc,numero,periodo from bill)  AS bill 
INNER JOIN (select id,comprobante,suc,numero from details_bill)  
AS details_bill 
ON (bill.Comprobante = details_bill.Comprobante) 
AND (bill.Suc = details_bill.Suc) AND (bill.Numero = details_bill.Numero)
GROUP BY bill.Periodo;
```

how can I get the correct number in the "Count(bill.Id) AS bill_counts" field?

Comment: Add to your group by clause to include bill.Id since you are calling Count on it, you need to group like bill.ids, so GROUP BY bill.Periodo, bill.Id

Comment: If one or more of these answers has solved your issue please award the green tick to the answer that you deem is best / most educational.  If neither solves your issue, please leave them comments that describes what is not yet right.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS` to avoid duplicates at all

```
SELECT bill.Periodo, Count(bill.Id) AS bill_counts
FROM bill 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM details_bill
   WHERE bill.Comprobante = details_bill.Comprobante AND 
         bill.Suc = details_bill.Suc AND 
         bill.Numero = details_bill.Numero
)
GROUP BY bill.Periodo;
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access doesn't support `SELECT DISTINCT`.  A simple change is to move the connection to the detail table into an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT b.Periodo, Count(*) AS bill_counts
FROM bill AS b 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM details_bill as db
              WHERE b.Comprobante = db.Comprobante AND
                    b.Suc = db.Suc AND
                    b.Numero = db.Numero
             )
GROUP BY bill.Periodo;
```